# Why are Fauxwood vertical blinds not as thick as Fauxwood horizontal blinds?

Tags: lighting, windows, blinds, curtain-rail

Why are Fauxwood Vertical blinds not as thick as Fauxwood Horizontal blinds? I received a lot of samples. Is it because vertical blinds structure rail cannot hold something as heavy? I buy blinds, not only for lighting but as slight protection against window insulation during the winter months.

Comment: Ask the company. They would know what, if any, reason there was for the difference. Unlikely that anyone here does.

Comment: hi @Ecnerwal this is for many different types of brands, I asked customer service, they didn't really know either

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just a guess, but something held vertically from the top and still be straight, doe not need to be thick at all. Now take the same piece of material used horizontally and it will potentially sag between supports. Thicker material will withstand sagging over a given distance, especially over time where gravity will deflect an item that may have been straight initially.

Answer (score 1):

At the first glance, there seems no logical reason for them to use two different thicknesses for horizontal and vertical blinds. For vertical blinds, thicker material will cause more sag and increased difficulty in open-close the blinds due to more friction, but these are not problems usually associated with the horizontal blinds, then, why use thicker material for horizontal blinds? My guess is that because of exactly the same reason - to prevent sagging, but of different parts. While the horizontal blinds need more rigidity to span the opening without the blind leaf from sagging, the vertical blinds need to reduce the hanging weight of the vertical leaf that causes sag to occur.

[image]